# tkinter wm_grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'

Tags: python, tkinter

In line 11 I tried to use the grid(), but it keeps giving me
"wm_grid() got an unexpected keyword argument 'row'" error
Can anyone take a look at this?

```
import tkinter as tk


class MainPage(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # pass frames as dictionaries
        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
# problem here****************************************************
        frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
# problem here****************************************************          
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, controller):
        frame = self.frames[controller]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="StartPage")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

root = MainPage()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what are you trying to create?

Comment: In case anyone else is wondering why we get so many tkinter questions with almost identical code, it is coming from here: http://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the issue for you comes because you are subclassing `StartPage` from `tk.Tk` , you cannot use `row`/`column` keyword arguments for `grid` in that case.

But I believe that you really did not intend it to be a subclass of `tk.Tk` , since you seem to be trying to initialize `tk.Frame` inside it. I believe the fix in your case would be to inherit the class from `tk.Frame` instead as -

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped